# function to use slidertabs external

Tags: jquery

Using: http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/

I want to beable to create an external function to slide the slider right. so if im on slide 2, and set the function to a click handler it will slide to the next.

I don't understand how to do this.

Here is a fiddle of the JS SliderTabs uses:

`code`

http://jsfiddle.net/LueFn/

I see this question, but no answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343885/jquery-slidertabs-custom-next-function  Same idea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tabs = $("div#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();

  $('#link').click(function(e){
     // e.preventDefault();
      //var tabs = $("#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();

      tabs.next();
      //$("#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();
      //$("#mySliderTabs").data().next();
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**
You need the v1.1 version of [jquery.sliderTabs.js](https://github.com/lopatin/sliderTabs) for this to work
The next() function is nested  one level down in the data object
**/edit**

You can access the sliderTabs instance in the following way:

```
// as a cached var
var tabs = $("#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();
tabs.sliderTabs.next();

// access the instance on the element directly
$("#mySliderTabs").sliderTabs();
$("#mySliderTabs").data("sliderTabs").next();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  i tried this, and I am getting data is undefined.

Comment: then show some relevant code, how do you implement the sliderTabs?
The jsfiddle just shows the sliderTabs source

Comment: why post code in a comment? edit your question or update your jsfiddle please

Comment: I didnt know how it would look, but i updated the question. I realized it when I posted it.

Comment: still a jsfiddle displaying your problem would help.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in jsfiddle, i copied the code to http://jsbin.com/nanureda/1/edit  When click next, want it to go to next slide, click again next slide

Comment: It looks like you're not using the latest jquery.sliderTabs.js from github ?

Comment: sorry, i am directly linking to the one on his site ?

Comment: That version seams to be v.1.0. The v1.1 can either be downloaded from http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/sliderTabs-1.1.zip or https://github.com/lopatin/sliderTabs

Comment: I put a new js with v1.1, still doesn't seem to do anything, i added an alert to make sure doc ready was working, and click function, and it did.. http://jsbin.com/nanureda/3/edit

Comment: Well I got it working!  It was actually `tabs.data('sliderTabs').next()`

Comment: Yes, just didn't need the: $("#mySliderTabs")  Thanks so much!